# TYPO3 only one category selectable in backend

Tags: typo3, categories

I have a record which has a field called type which uses the TYPO3 category API.

Basically I did that:

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable(
    'my_ext',
    'my_table_name',
    'type',
    [
        'label' => 'Type',
        'exclude' => false,
        'config' => [
            'eval' => 'required',
        ]
    ]
);
```

When I edit such a record I can choose as many categories as I want. In fact, I want that the enduser can only choose one.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the documentation which explains [how to make a table categorizable](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Categories/#making-a-table-categorizable). Here you can see that the 4th parameter of `ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable()` itself does not allow for full TCA overrides, but you can use its `fieldConfiguration` subsection to set [`maxitems`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/singlehtml/Index.html#id129) as desired:

```php
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable(
        'my_ext',
        'my_table_name',
        'type',
        [
            'label' => 'Type',
            'exclude' => false,
            'fieldConfiguration' => [
                'eval' => 'required',
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ],
        ]
    );
```